# Vue For Loop not working correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to create a logic to run over array of objects but I am facing a problem in correctly putting it in the template, Does anyone have idea how it will work, Example is below:-

```
arrayElement: [
              {"name":xy,"age":1},
              {"name":xy,"age":2},
              {"name":xy,"age":3},
              {"name":xy,"age":4},
              {"name":yz,"age":1},
              {"name":yz,"age":2},
              {"name":u,"age":1},
              {"name":u,"age":2},
                   ]
```

This is the array and now I want to disply the elements in the data table but xy should have all the element associated with it and yz too same applicable to u.

```
<template slot="items" slot-scope="props">
  <div>{{props.item.name}}</div>
  <div v-for="item in items"> <input>{{props.item.age}}</input></div>
</template>
```

I am doing somthing like this but it is giving me every row like this

```
xy 1
xy  2
xy  3
xy  4
```

But I want like this

```
xy    1
      2
      3
      4

yz    1
      2

 u    1
      2
```

Comment: Are you able to modify your `arrayElement`?

Comment: No, I want to display in a row a single element with multiple values as shown above  so all the similar name i.e xy should display all the values associated with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to build another collection which is a "calculated" value. You can then use that collection to iterate as per your need.

For example,

```
{
xy: [1,2,3,4],
yz:  [1,2],
u: [1]
}
```

Edit: Added the plain JS version of how to transform it.
You can use this and make a Vue computed property.

```js
//Data
var orig = [
              {"name":'xy',"age":1},
              {"name":'xy',"age":2},
              {"name":'xy',"age":3},
              {"name":'xy',"age":4},
              {"name":'yz',"age":1},
              {"name":'yz',"age":2},
              {"name":'u',"age":1},
              {"name":'u',"age":2}
                   ];

//Define function
function makeMultimap(input){
  var out = {}; //Object ~ Dictionary ~ HashMap
  for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++){
    var row = input[i];
    var name = row.name;
    var age = row.age;
    var outVal = out[name];
    if(outVal==undefined){
      out[name] = [];
      outVal = out[name];
    }
    outVal.push(age);
  }

  console.log(input);
  console.log(out);
}

//Execute by passing data
makeMultimap(orig);
```

In Vue that would be something like this:

```
computed:{
 arrayMultiMap: function(input){
      var out = {}; //Object ~ Dictionary ~ HashMap
      for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        var row = input[i];
        var name = row.name;
        var age = row.age;
        var outVal = out[name];
        if(outVal==undefined){
          out[name] = [];
          outVal = out[name];
        }
        outVal.push(age);
      }

      console.log(input);
      console.log(out);

      return out;
    }
}
```

Now you can use `arrayMultiMap` as if it was a property.

Comment: Can you give me some hit how to generate this collection?

Comment: Can you tell me how to traverse with the output now as it will return me something like this,     `{"xy":[1,24,2,25,3,26,4,27]}`  and now I want to display like this in a table `xy -> 1 24 in a line and another like should be 2 25, third line should be 3 26` so this is the single row with xy and values whould be age and year